# Spring JDBC No suitable driver found for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver

Tags: swing, spring-jdbc

Hi I am trying to connect SQL Server with JDBC JTDS but it turn out an error: No suitable driver found for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver, I already put it in my dependency and it appear on the Maven library, this is my configure for datasource:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />       
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/mkyongjava;instance=SQLEXPRESS" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="admin123" />
</bean>
```

I already put jtds driver on Tomcat Server but no thing change

[This is my project stuture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB5jf.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are still providing the MySQL driver class name in the `driverClassName` property - try changing that to:

`<property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />`